# Cant post to backend

Tags: java, android, spring

Backend code on `Spring`.

```
@PostMapping("/results")
public void postResults(@RequestBody List<Result> list)
{
    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

`Android` code:

```
void post(List<Result> list)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    //Failure point
    restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, json, null);
}
```

This fails with an Exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415  at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)

Comment: Http 415 means media type is not supported

Comment: Do you have any implementation to deal with json data on the spring side?

Comment: No, it looks just like what I posted above. Should I change the backend method to take a String?

Comment: add the consumes attribute to `@PostMapping`  and mention application/json

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on your error log, **Error Code 415** means **Unsupported Media Type**. So you should add header to indicate your media type.

```
void post(List<Result> list)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(json, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.put(url, entity);
}
```